# going forward in a player skipping certain amount of frames

Tags: video, media-player, movie

I have several video-files in *.avi format. And here is a problem requiring a solution. Depending on the movie, I wish to play it forward, using keyboard, skipping user-defined amount of frames. For example, in QuickTime there is a possibility to play a movie forward and back frame-by-frame using right and left arrows on a keyboard respectively. I would like, in particular, to have a possibility to use "up" and "down" arrows to skip for example 30 frames forward and backward. And I would like to have the possibility to define the number of frames I would like to skip.

So the best simple solution for me would be just pointing out at a player that has this feature. But any input is welcome.

Comment: the most important thing to me is just to be able to skip certain amounts of frames in both directions

Comment: I just ran into this -- are you still interested?  There are some options out there,

Comment: yes, please, if you've got some ideas, share them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a laundry-list of players with various levels of support for frame-stepping in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/45803/video-players-that-have-frame-by-frame-playback-feature). It is mostly about *single* frame forth and back though.

However, a plugin [`Jump to time`](http://addons.videolan.org/content/show.php/Previous+frame?content=156396) for `VLC` gets mentioned (at that time still called 'Previous frame'), with a link to [this post](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6907/video-player-with-backward-frame-by-frame-stepping-for-linux/11585#11585).  The picture there is very promising while the discussion seems outdated given how much more the current version can do.

The page of the extension, linked above, states

> Jump to time (Previous frame) is VLC Extension that can:
>   - jump to a desired time in a played media;
>   - jump forward/backward by a desired time length;
>   - split-second jumps imitating previous/next frame;*
>   - show actual playback time with milliseconds;
>   - use time longer than 24 hours;
>   - repeat a desired scene again and again (A-loop);
>   - convert time.
>   It cannot make a cup of coffee for you :-)

The one-frame jumps apparently aren't super accurate but that may not affect your need.

This seems to come very close to the stated purpose of analysis.  I don't know whether it'll be as simple as 'up-down' with adjustable frame-step, but it may well be usable enough.

Another option certainly worth looking into is [`VirtualDub`](http://www.virtualdub.org/index) which can do virtually anything with a stream.  I'd be surprised if it weren't possible to use it for described analysis at least to some extent.

Both `VLC` and `VirtualDub` are well known and respected tools that have been around for a long while.

Finally, if you are up to some programming, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336955/how-to-step-one-frame-forward-and-one-frame-backward-in-video-playback) is about how to accomplish customizable jumps using `HTML` and `Javascript`.